# Can anyone help me with a PIPELINED function?

Tags: oracle, function, plsql, oracle12c

I am developing a function in Oracle 12c, which takes data from several tables and returns a header row and after each header a list of values ​​related to it.
Explaining it better, I have several localities or cities, within which there are electricity consumers, which are identified by a category according to the use they give to electricity, and by their consumption in kWh.
The function must return each of the towns in the header row (plus the titles), and then a grouping for each category of that town; and so on for each of the cities.
I thought I would solve the question with two (2) cursors, one to group by location and the other internal to the first one to group by category.
When I compile no error appears, but on execution, Oracle warns me of this error:

> ORA-06502: PL / SQL: error: numeric or value string buffer too small
>
> ORA-06512: in "CEMDO_DB.XXLOCALIDADPORCATEGORIA1", line 87
>
> ORA-06512:in "CEMDO_DB.XXLOCALIDADPORCATEGORIA1", line 87
>
> 6502. 00000 - "PL / SQL: numeric or value error% s"
>
> - Cause: An arithmetic, numeric, string, conversion, or constraint error
>   occurred. For example, this error occurs if an attempt is made to
>   assign the value NULL to a variable declared NOT NULL, or if an
>   attempt is made to assign an integer larger than 99 to a variable
>   declared NUMBER (2).
> - Action: Change the data, how it is manipulated, or how it is declared so
>   that values ​​do not violate constraints.*

It does not clarify me about the cause, because I have no problems with value types or variable capacity. The only thing I have on the error line is a PIPE ROW.
In the Debug of the function, the error message is as follows:

> ORA-06550: line 10, column 3:
>
> PL / SQL: ORA-00904: "XXLXC1_ROW": invalid identifier
>
> ORA-06550: line 9, column 5:
>
> PL / SQL: SQL Statement ignored

Here the error is made explicit, but I can't find a way to solve it because the PIPE ROW xxLxC1 type is declared and is present within the schema objects.

Sorry for the inconvenience, but this is my third feature written for Oracle, as I have been working with Informix for 20 years.

From now on, I thank you for your attention.

I copy the code of the function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION xxLocalidadPorCategoria1( pAnio NUMBER, pNroPer NUMBER ) RETURN xxLxC1_tab PIPELINED IS

CURSOR curLoc IS
    SELECT cc.IdCategoria, cat.Descripcion, f.IdLocalidad, l.Descripcion Localidad
    FROM Cbtes_Coop cc, Cbtes_Cptos ccp, Suministros s, SubFincas sf, Fincas f, Categorias cat, 
    Localidades l -----, OUTER( Sim_Cbtes sc, OUTER( Categorias cat, Suministros s, Localidades l ))
       WHERE cc.Anio = pAnio
       AND cc.NroPer = pNroPer
       AND cc.Estado != 'X'
       AND cc.IdTipo_Srv = 1
    ----AND cc.IdSuministro = 1078      ----Agregada para control
       AND cc.IdEmpresa = ccp.IdEmpresa
       AND cc.IdSucursal = ccp.IdSucursal
       AND cc.Tipo_Cbte = ccp.Tipo_Cbte
       AND cc.Grupo_Cbte = ccp.Grupo_Cbte
       AND cc.Letra_Cbte = ccp.Letra_Cbte
       AND cc.NroCbte = ccp.NroCbte
       AND ccp.IdConcepto IN ( SELECT IdConcepto FROM Conceptos WHERE IdTipo_Srv = 1 )
       AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT IdEmpresa
                           FROM Cbtes_Coop
                           WHERE IdCbte_Padre = cc.IdCbte
                           AND IdSucursal IN ( 4, 47, 48 )
                           AND Tipo_Cbte = 'NC'
                           AND IdTipo_ModoFac > 0
                           AND Estado != 'X'
                           AND ABS( Totalimp ) = ABS( cc.Totalimp ))
       AND cc.IdSuministro = s.IdSuministro
       AND s.IdSubFinca = sf.IdSubFinca
       AND sf.IdFinca = f.IdFinca
       AND f.IdLocalidad = l.IdLocalidad
       AND cc.IdTipo_Srv = cat.IdTipo_Srv
       AND cc.IdCategoria = cat.IdCategoria
            GROUP BY cc.IdCategoria, cat.Descripcion, f.IdLocalidad, l.Descripcion
            ORDER BY 1;

CURSOR curTemp (pIdLocalidad NUMBER) IS
    SELECT cc.IdCategoria, cat.Descripcion, f.IdLocalidad, l.Descripcion Localidad, SUM( CASE WHEN 
    ccp.IdConcepto = 5 THEN 1 END ) Cargo_Fijo, SUM( CASE WHEN ccp.IdConcepto = 5 THEN ccp.Importe 
    END ) Importe_C_Fijo, SUM( CASE WHEN ccp.IdConcepto = 10 THEN ROUND( ccp.Unidades, 2 ) END ) kWh, 
    SUM( CASE WHEN ccp.IdConcepto = 10 THEN ccp.Importe END ) Importe_Consumo, SUM( CASE WHEN 
    ccp.IdConcepto IN( 35, 38 ) THEN 1 END) Cargo_Fijo_GC, SUM( CASE WHEN ccp.IdConcepto IN( 35, 38 ) 
    THEN ccp.Importe END ) Imp_C_Fijo_GC, SUM( CASE WHEN ccp.IdConcepto IN( 30, 31, 32 ) THEN ROUND( 
    ccp.Unidades, 2 ) END ) Energia_GC, SUM( CASE WHEN ccp.IdConcepto IN( 30, 31, 32 ) THEN 
    ccp.Importe END ) Importe_GC, SUM( CASE WHEN ccp.IdConcepto IN( 40, 41 ) THEN ROUND( 
    ccp.Unidades, 2 ) END ) Unidades_Demanda, SUM( CASE WHEN ccp.IdConcepto IN( 40, 41 ) THEN 
    ccp.Importe END ) Importe_Demanda, SUM( CASE WHEN ccp.IdConcepto IN( 101, 109 ) THEN 1 END ) 
    Cant_BEN, SUM( CASE WHEN ccp.IdConcepto IN( 101, 109 ) THEN ccp.Importe END ) BEN, SUM( CASE WHEN 
    ccp.IdConcepto = 62 AND ccp.Importe != 0 THEN 1 END ) Ajuste_Coseno, SUM(CASE WHEN ccp.IdConcepto 
    = 62 AND ccp.Importe != 0 THEN ccp.Importe END ) Imp_Ajuste_Coseno, SUM(CASE WHEN ccp.IdConcepto 
    IN ( 25, 26, 27, 29, 291,292, 293, 294, 295 ) THEN 1 END ) 
   Cant_Cargos_Ersep, SUM( CASE WHEN ccp.IdConcepto IN ( 25, 26, 27, 29, 291,292, 293, 294, 295 ) 
   THEN ccp.Importe END ) Imp_Cargos_Ersep, SUM( CASE WHEN ccp.IdConcepto IN ( 20, 21, 23, 24, 64, 
   100, 432, 433, 434 ) THEN 1 END ) Cant_Ajustes_Ersep, SUM( CASE WHEN ccp.IdConcepto IN ( 20, 21, 
   23, 24, 64, 100, 432, 433, 434 ) THEN ccp.Importe END ) Imp_Ajustes_Ersep, SUM( CASE WHEN 
   ccp.IdConcepto IN( 28, 97, 98 ) AND ccp.IdSubConcepto IN( 0,1,2,3 ) THEN 1 END ) Unid_Bonif_Exc, 
   SUM( CASE WHEN ccp.IdConcepto IN( 28, 97, 98 ) AND ccp.IdSubConcepto IN( 0,1,2,3 ) THEN 
   ccp.Importe END ) Imp_Bonif_Exc, SUM( CASE WHEN ccp.IdConcepto IN( 438, 439 ) AND 
   ccp.IdSubConcepto = 0 THEN 1 END ) Unid_Reajustes, SUM( CASE WHEN 
   ccp.IdConcepto IN( 438, 439 ) AND ccp.IdSubConcepto = 0 THEN ccp.Importe END ) Imp_Reajustes, SUM( 
   CASE WHEN ccp.IdConcepto = 58 AND ccp.IdSubConcepto = 0 THEN 1 END ) Unid_Coie, SUM( CASE WHEN 
   ccp.IdConcepto = 58 AND ccp.IdSubConcepto = 0 THEN ccp.Importe END ) Imp_Coie, SUM( CASE WHEN 
   ccp.IdConcepto = 296 AND ccp.IdSubConcepto = 0 THEN 1 END ) Unid_Coie_Dem, SUM( CASE WHEN 
   ccp.IdConcepto = 296 AND ccp.IdSubConcepto = 0 THEN ccp.Importe END ) Imp_Coie_Dem, SUM( CASE WHEN 
   ccp.IdConcepto = 103 AND ccp.Importe < 0 THEN 1 END ) Unid_TRA1, SUM( CASE WHEN ccp.IdConcepto = 
   103 AND ccp.Importe < 0 THEN ccp.Importe END ) Imp_TRA1, SUM( CASE WHEN ccp.IdConcepto = 104 AND 
   ccp.Importe < 0 THEN 1 END ) Unid_TRA2, SUM( CASE WHEN ccp.IdConcepto = 104 AND ccp.Importe < 0 
   THEN ccp.Importe END ) Imp_TRA2, SUM( CASE WHEN ccp.IdConcepto = 102 AND ccp.Importe < 0 THEN 1 
   END ) Unid_TSCA, SUM( CASE WHEN ccp.IdConcepto = 102 AND ccp.Importe < 0 THEN ccp.Importe END ) 
   Imp_TSCA, SUM( CASE WHEN ccp.IdConcepto = 105 AND ccp.Importe < 0 THEN 1 END ) Unid_TSSA, SUM( 
   CASE WHEN ccp.IdConcepto = 105 AND ccp.Importe < 0 THEN ccp.Importe END ) Imp_TSSA, SUM( CASE WHEN 
   ccp.IdConcepto = 443 AND ccp.Importe < 0 THEN 1 END ) UnidBonifCemdo, SUM( CASE WHEN 
   ccp.IdConcepto = 443 AND ccp.Importe < 0 THEN ccp.Importe END ) ImpBonifCemdo, SUM( CASE WHEN 
   ccp.IdConcepto = 121 AND ccp.Importe < 0 THEN 1 END ) UnidTSPC, SUM( CASE WHEN ccp.IdConcepto = 
   121 AND ccp.Importe < 0  THEN ccp.Importe END ) ImpTSPC, SUM( CASE WHEN ccp.IdConcepto = 122 AND 
   ccp.Importe < 0 THEN 1 END ) UnidTSPI, SUM( CASE WHEN ccp.IdConcepto = 122 AND ccp.Importe < 0  
   THEN ccp.Importe END ) ImpTSPI
      FROM Cbtes_Coop cc, Cbtes_Cptos ccp, Suministros s, SubFincas sf, Fincas f, Categorias cat, 
      Localidades l 
         WHERE cc.Anio = pAnio
         AND cc.NroPer = pNroPer
         AND cc.Estado != 'X'
         AND cc.IdTipo_Srv = 1
         ----AND cc.IdSuministro = 1078     ----Agregada para control
         AND cc.IdEmpresa = ccp.IdEmpresa
        AND cc.IdSucursal = ccp.IdSucursal
        AND cc.Tipo_Cbte = ccp.Tipo_Cbte
        AND cc.Grupo_Cbte = ccp.Grupo_Cbte
        AND cc.Letra_Cbte = ccp.Letra_Cbte
        AND cc.NroCbte = ccp.NroCbte
        AND ccp.IdConcepto IN ( SELECT IdConcepto FROM Conceptos WHERE IdTipo_Srv = 1 )
        AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT IdEmpresa
                            FROM Cbtes_Coop
                            WHERE IdCbte_Padre = cc.IdCbte
                            AND IdSucursal IN ( 4, 47, 48 )
                            AND Tipo_Cbte = 'NC'
                            AND IdTipo_ModoFac > 0
                            AND Estado != 'X'
                            AND ABS( Totalimp ) = ABS( cc.Totalimp ))
        AND cc.IdSuministro = s.IdSuministro
        AND s.IdSubFinca = sf.IdSubFinca
        AND sf.IdFinca = f.IdFinca
        AND f.IdLocalidad = l.IdLocalidad
        AND cc.IdTipo_Srv = cat.IdTipo_Srv
        AND cc.IdCategoria = cat.IdCategoria
        AND f.IdLocalidad = pIdLocalidad
            GROUP BY f.IdLocalidad, l.Descripcion, cc.IdCategoria, cat.Descripcion
            /*GROUPING SETS((f.IdLocalidad, l.Descripcion, cc.IdCategoria, cat.Descripcion))*/
            ORDER BY f.IdLocalidad, cc.IdCategoria;

BEGIN
    FOR regLoc IN curLoc LOOP
        PIPE ROW (xxLxC1_row( TO_CHAR(regLoc.IdLocalidad) || '-' || regLoc.Localidad, 'Cargo Fijo', 
'Imp. Cargo Fijo', 'Consumo', 'Imp. Consumo', 'C. Fijo GC', 'Imp. C. Fijo GC', 'Consumo GC', 'Imp. 
Consumo GC', 'Unid. Demanda', 'Imp. Demanda', 'Bonificaciones', 'Imp. Bonificaciones', 'Coseno PHI', 
'Imp. Coseno PHI', 'Cargos ERSeP', 'Imp. Cargos ERSeP',
'Ajustes ERSeP', 'Imp. Ajustes ERSeP', 'Unid. Bonif. Exc', 'Imp. Bonif. Exc.', 'Unid. Reajustes', 
'Imp. Reajustes', 'Unid. COIE', 'Imp. COIE', 'Unid. COIE Dem.', 'Imp. COIE Dem', 'Unid. TRA1', 'Imp. 
TRA1', 'Unid. TRA2', 'Imp. TRA2', 'Unid. TSCA', 'Imp. TSCA', 'Unid. TSSA', 'Imp. TSSA', 'Unid. Bonif. 
Cemdo', 'Imp. Bonif. Cemdo', 'Unid. TSPC', 'Imp. TSPC', 'Unid. TSPI', 'Imp. TSPI'));
    FOR regTemp IN curTemp(regLoc.IdLocalidad) LOOP
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(regLoc.IdLocalidad);
        PIPE ROW (xxLxC1_row(regTemp.IdCategoria || '-' || regTemp.Descripcion, regTemp.Cargo_Fijo, 
        regTemp.Importe_C_Fijo, regTemp.kWh, regTemp.Importe_Consumo, regTemp.Cargo_Fijo_GC, 
        regTemp.Imp_C_Fijo_GC, regTemp.Energia_GC, regTemp.Importe_GC, regTemp.Unidades_Demanda, 
        regTemp.Importe_Demanda, regTemp.Cant_BEN, regTemp.BEN, regTemp.Ajuste_Coseno, 
        regTemp.Imp_Ajuste_Coseno, regTemp.Cant_Cargos_Ersep, regTemp.Imp_Cargos_Ersep,
        regTemp.Cant_Ajustes_Ersep, regTemp.Imp_Ajustes_Ersep, regTemp.Unid_Bonif_Exc, 
        regTemp.Imp_Bonif_Exc, regTemp.Unid_Reajustes, regTemp.Imp_Reajustes, regTemp.Unid_Coie, 
        regTemp.Imp_Coie, regTemp.Unid_Coie_Dem, regTemp.Imp_Coie_Dem, regTemp.Unid_TRA1, 
        regTemp.Imp_TRA1, regTemp.Unid_TRA2, regTemp.Imp_TRA2, regTemp.Unid_TSCA, regTemp.Imp_TSCA, 
        regTemp.Unid_TSSA, regTemp.Imp_TSSA, regTemp.UnidBonifCemdo, regTemp.ImpBonifCemdo,
        regTemp.UnidTSPC, regTemp.ImpTSPC, regTemp.UnidTSPI, regTemp.ImpTSPI));
     END LOOP;
    
    END LOOP;
END;
/
```

And the code of PIPE ROW and VIRTUAL TABLE:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE xxLxC1_row AS OBJECT (c1 Varchar2(50), c2 Varchar2(20), c3 Varchar2(20), c4 Varchar2(20), c5 Varchar2(20), c6 Varchar2(20), c7 Varchar2(20), c8 Varchar2(20), c9 Varchar2(20), c10 Varchar2(20), c11 Varchar2(20), c12 Varchar2(20), c13 Varchar2(20), c14 Varchar2(20), c15 Varchar2(20), c16 Varchar2(20), c17 Varchar2(20), c18 Varchar2(20), c19 Varchar2(20), c20 Varchar2(20), c21 Varchar2(20), c22 Varchar2(20), c23 Varchar2(20), c24 Varchar2(20), c25 Varchar2(20), c26 Varchar2(20), c27 Varchar2(20), c28 Varchar2(20), c29 Varchar2(20), c30 Varchar2(20), c31 Varchar2(20), c32 Varchar2(20), c33 Varchar2(20), c34 Varchar2(20), c35 Varchar2(20), c36 Varchar2(20), c37 Varchar2(20), c38 Varchar2(20), c39 Varchar2(20), c40 Varchar2(20), c41 Varchar2(20));
/

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE xxLxC1_tab AS TABLE OF xxLxC1_row;
/
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [MRE] which includes the DDL (`CREATE TABLE` and `CREATE TYPE`) statements for the tables and data types so that we can run your function and replicate the error. You are much more likely to get help (especially with a huge block of code) if we do not have to try to reverse engineer your code to be able to run it.

Comment: @MT0 I have added the code, but I cannot add the code of each intervening table, since there are several and very, very large.

Comment: Then add a [MRE] with enough information to compile the function (we don't want the full definition for the table, we only want enough to make it work). Similar to how you don't need to give us all the columns in the tables, you can edit out all the unnecessary columns from the function and the type; if you have the same issue with 4 columns as with 41 columns then why give us 41 columns ... make it minimal.

Comment: @GustavoEchenique Since the error happens on the PIPE ROW line, perhaps one of the variables in the TYPE is not large enough. In the function, go through each column one-at-a-time, replace the variable with an empty string, and find out which one is causing the error.

Comment: Writing the headers as first record looks a bit strange to me. Usually you set them as attributes in the object (instead of c1, c2, c3...). NB, the `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE` may raise an exception in production code if the DBMS_OUTPUT buffer overflows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every single element of your object type is VARCHAR2(20), so one of the values you are piping out is most likely larger than 20 bytes long.

For the FIRST pipe row, given that all of the values you are piping out are constants and those constants are less than 20 characters, then the only candidate for an error is

```
 TO_CHAR(regLoc.IdLocalidad) || '-' || regLoc.Localidad
```

being longer than 20 characters. However, for the SECOND pipe row, every one of those values is coming out of a cursor fetch, so any of those values could be the culprit.

An easy way to cycle through the data is just to slightly alter your function to temporarily be a non pipelined one and then just loop through the data and perform an object assignment to check, ie

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION xxLocalidadPorCategoria1( pAnio NUMBER, pNroPer NUMBER ) RETURN number IS

my_row xxLxC1_row;

CURSOR curLoc IS
    SELECT cc.IdCategoria, cat.Descripcion, f.IdLocalidad, l.Descripcion Localidad
    FROM Cbtes_Coop cc, Cbtes_Cptos ccp, Suministros s, SubFincas sf, Fincas f, Categorias cat, 
    Localidades l -----, OUTER( Sim_Cbtes sc, OUTER( Categorias cat, Suministros s, Localidades l ))
       WHERE cc.Anio = pAnio
       AND cc.NroPer = pNroPer
       AND cc.Estado != 'X'
       AND cc.IdTipo_Srv = 1
    ----AND cc.IdSuministro = 1078      ----Agregada para control
       AND cc.IdEmpresa = ccp.IdEmpresa
       AND cc.IdSucursal = ccp.IdSucursal
       AND cc.Tipo_Cbte = ccp.Tipo_Cbte
       AND cc.Grupo_Cbte = ccp.Grupo_Cbte
       AND cc.Letra_Cbte = ccp.Letra_Cbte
       AND cc.NroCbte = ccp.NroCbte
       AND ccp.IdConcepto IN ( SELECT IdConcepto FROM Conceptos WHERE IdTipo_Srv = 1 )
       AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT IdEmpresa
                           FROM Cbtes_Coop
                           WHERE IdCbte_Padre = cc.IdCbte
                           AND IdSucursal IN ( 4, 47, 48 )
                           AND Tipo_Cbte = 'NC'
                           AND IdTipo_ModoFac > 0
                           AND Estado != 'X'
                           AND ABS( Totalimp ) = ABS( cc.Totalimp ))
       AND cc.IdSuministro = s.IdSuministro
       AND s.IdSubFinca = sf.IdSubFinca
       AND sf.IdFinca = f.IdFinca
       AND f.IdLocalidad = l.IdLocalidad
       AND cc.IdTipo_Srv = cat.IdTipo_Srv
       AND cc.IdCategoria = cat.IdCategoria
            GROUP BY cc.IdCategoria, cat.Descripcion, f.IdLocalidad, l.Descripcion
            ORDER BY 1;

CURSOR curTemp (pIdLocalidad NUMBER) IS
    SELECT cc.IdCategoria, cat.Descripcion, f.IdLocalidad, l.Descripcion Localidad, SUM( CASE WHEN 
    ccp.IdConcepto = 5 THEN 1 END ) Cargo_Fijo, SUM( CASE WHEN ccp.IdConcepto = 5 THEN ccp.Importe 
    END ) Importe_C_Fijo, SUM( CASE WHEN ccp.IdConcepto = 10 THEN ROUND( ccp.Unidades, 2 ) END ) kWh, 
    SUM( CASE WHEN ccp.IdConcepto = 10 THEN ccp.Importe END ) Importe_Consumo, SUM( CASE WHEN 
    ccp.IdConcepto IN( 35, 38 ) THEN 1 END) Cargo_Fijo_GC, SUM( CASE WHEN ccp.IdConcepto IN( 35, 38 ) 
    THEN ccp.Importe END ) Imp_C_Fijo_GC, SUM( CASE WHEN ccp.IdConcepto IN( 30, 31, 32 ) THEN ROUND( 
    ccp.Unidades, 2 ) END ) Energia_GC, SUM( CASE WHEN ccp.IdConcepto IN( 30, 31, 32 ) THEN 
    ccp.Importe END ) Importe_GC, SUM( CASE WHEN ccp.IdConcepto IN( 40, 41 ) THEN ROUND( 
    ccp.Unidades, 2 ) END ) Unidades_Demanda, SUM( CASE WHEN ccp.IdConcepto IN( 40, 41 ) THEN 
    ccp.Importe END ) Importe_Demanda, SUM( CASE WHEN ccp.IdConcepto IN( 101, 109 ) THEN 1 END ) 
    Cant_BEN, SUM( CASE WHEN ccp.IdConcepto IN( 101, 109 ) THEN ccp.Importe END ) BEN, SUM( CASE WHEN 
    ccp.IdConcepto = 62 AND ccp.Importe != 0 THEN 1 END ) Ajuste_Coseno, SUM(CASE WHEN ccp.IdConcepto 
    = 62 AND ccp.Importe != 0 THEN ccp.Importe END ) Imp_Ajuste_Coseno, SUM(CASE WHEN ccp.IdConcepto 
    IN ( 25, 26, 27, 29, 291,292, 293, 294, 295 ) THEN 1 END ) 
   Cant_Cargos_Ersep, SUM( CASE WHEN ccp.IdConcepto IN ( 25, 26, 27, 29, 291,292, 293, 294, 295 ) 
   THEN ccp.Importe END ) Imp_Cargos_Ersep, SUM( CASE WHEN ccp.IdConcepto IN ( 20, 21, 23, 24, 64, 
   100, 432, 433, 434 ) THEN 1 END ) Cant_Ajustes_Ersep, SUM( CASE WHEN ccp.IdConcepto IN ( 20, 21, 
   23, 24, 64, 100, 432, 433, 434 ) THEN ccp.Importe END ) Imp_Ajustes_Ersep, SUM( CASE WHEN 
   ccp.IdConcepto IN( 28, 97, 98 ) AND ccp.IdSubConcepto IN( 0,1,2,3 ) THEN 1 END ) Unid_Bonif_Exc, 
   SUM( CASE WHEN ccp.IdConcepto IN( 28, 97, 98 ) AND ccp.IdSubConcepto IN( 0,1,2,3 ) THEN 
   ccp.Importe END ) Imp_Bonif_Exc, SUM( CASE WHEN ccp.IdConcepto IN( 438, 439 ) AND 
   ccp.IdSubConcepto = 0 THEN 1 END ) Unid_Reajustes, SUM( CASE WHEN 
   ccp.IdConcepto IN( 438, 439 ) AND ccp.IdSubConcepto = 0 THEN ccp.Importe END ) Imp_Reajustes, SUM( 
   CASE WHEN ccp.IdConcepto = 58 AND ccp.IdSubConcepto = 0 THEN 1 END ) Unid_Coie, SUM( CASE WHEN 
   ccp.IdConcepto = 58 AND ccp.IdSubConcepto = 0 THEN ccp.Importe END ) Imp_Coie, SUM( CASE WHEN 
   ccp.IdConcepto = 296 AND ccp.IdSubConcepto = 0 THEN 1 END ) Unid_Coie_Dem, SUM( CASE WHEN 
   ccp.IdConcepto = 296 AND ccp.IdSubConcepto = 0 THEN ccp.Importe END ) Imp_Coie_Dem, SUM( CASE WHEN 
   ccp.IdConcepto = 103 AND ccp.Importe < 0 THEN 1 END ) Unid_TRA1, SUM( CASE WHEN ccp.IdConcepto = 
   103 AND ccp.Importe < 0 THEN ccp.Importe END ) Imp_TRA1, SUM( CASE WHEN ccp.IdConcepto = 104 AND 
   ccp.Importe < 0 THEN 1 END ) Unid_TRA2, SUM( CASE WHEN ccp.IdConcepto = 104 AND ccp.Importe < 0 
   THEN ccp.Importe END ) Imp_TRA2, SUM( CASE WHEN ccp.IdConcepto = 102 AND ccp.Importe < 0 THEN 1 
   END ) Unid_TSCA, SUM( CASE WHEN ccp.IdConcepto = 102 AND ccp.Importe < 0 THEN ccp.Importe END ) 
   Imp_TSCA, SUM( CASE WHEN ccp.IdConcepto = 105 AND ccp.Importe < 0 THEN 1 END ) Unid_TSSA, SUM( 
   CASE WHEN ccp.IdConcepto = 105 AND ccp.Importe < 0 THEN ccp.Importe END ) Imp_TSSA, SUM( CASE WHEN 
   ccp.IdConcepto = 443 AND ccp.Importe < 0 THEN 1 END ) UnidBonifCemdo, SUM( CASE WHEN 
   ccp.IdConcepto = 443 AND ccp.Importe < 0 THEN ccp.Importe END ) ImpBonifCemdo, SUM( CASE WHEN 
   ccp.IdConcepto = 121 AND ccp.Importe < 0 THEN 1 END ) UnidTSPC, SUM( CASE WHEN ccp.IdConcepto = 
   121 AND ccp.Importe < 0  THEN ccp.Importe END ) ImpTSPC, SUM( CASE WHEN ccp.IdConcepto = 122 AND 
   ccp.Importe < 0 THEN 1 END ) UnidTSPI, SUM( CASE WHEN ccp.IdConcepto = 122 AND ccp.Importe < 0  
   THEN ccp.Importe END ) ImpTSPI
      FROM Cbtes_Coop cc, Cbtes_Cptos ccp, Suministros s, SubFincas sf, Fincas f, Categorias cat, 
      Localidades l 
         WHERE cc.Anio = pAnio
         AND cc.NroPer = pNroPer
         AND cc.Estado != 'X'
         AND cc.IdTipo_Srv = 1
         ----AND cc.IdSuministro = 1078     ----Agregada para control
         AND cc.IdEmpresa = ccp.IdEmpresa
        AND cc.IdSucursal = ccp.IdSucursal
        AND cc.Tipo_Cbte = ccp.Tipo_Cbte
        AND cc.Grupo_Cbte = ccp.Grupo_Cbte
        AND cc.Letra_Cbte = ccp.Letra_Cbte
        AND cc.NroCbte = ccp.NroCbte
        AND ccp.IdConcepto IN ( SELECT IdConcepto FROM Conceptos WHERE IdTipo_Srv = 1 )
        AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT IdEmpresa
                            FROM Cbtes_Coop
                            WHERE IdCbte_Padre = cc.IdCbte
                            AND IdSucursal IN ( 4, 47, 48 )
                            AND Tipo_Cbte = 'NC'
                            AND IdTipo_ModoFac > 0
                            AND Estado != 'X'
                            AND ABS( Totalimp ) = ABS( cc.Totalimp ))
        AND cc.IdSuministro = s.IdSuministro
        AND s.IdSubFinca = sf.IdSubFinca
        AND sf.IdFinca = f.IdFinca
        AND f.IdLocalidad = l.IdLocalidad
        AND cc.IdTipo_Srv = cat.IdTipo_Srv
        AND cc.IdCategoria = cat.IdCategoria
        AND f.IdLocalidad = pIdLocalidad
            GROUP BY f.IdLocalidad, l.Descripcion, cc.IdCategoria, cat.Descripcion
            /*GROUPING SETS((f.IdLocalidad, l.Descripcion, cc.IdCategoria, cat.Descripcion))*/
            ORDER BY f.IdLocalidad, cc.IdCategoria;

BEGIN
    FOR regLoc IN curLoc LOOP
    
    
    --
    -- now we make sure this assignment works ok
    --
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(TO_CHAR(regLoc.IdLocalidad));
        my_row := xxLxC1_row( TO_CHAR(regLoc.IdLocalidad) || '-' || regLoc.Localidad, 'Cargo Fijo', 
'Imp. Cargo Fijo', 'Consumo', 'Imp. Consumo', 'C. Fijo GC', 'Imp. C. Fijo GC', 'Consumo GC', 'Imp. 
Consumo GC', 'Unid. Demanda', 'Imp. Demanda', 'Bonificaciones', 'Imp. Bonificaciones', 'Coseno PHI', 
'Imp. Coseno PHI', 'Cargos ERSeP', 'Imp. Cargos ERSeP',
'Ajustes ERSeP', 'Imp. Ajustes ERSeP', 'Unid. Bonif. Exc', 'Imp. Bonif. Exc.', 'Unid. Reajustes', 
'Imp. Reajustes', 'Unid. COIE', 'Imp. COIE', 'Unid. COIE Dem.', 'Imp. COIE Dem', 'Unid. TRA1', 'Imp. 
TRA1', 'Unid. TRA2', 'Imp. TRA2', 'Unid. TSCA', 'Imp. TSCA', 'Unid. TSSA', 'Imp. TSSA', 'Unid. Bonif. 
Cemdo', 'Imp. Bonif. Cemdo', 'Unid. TSPC', 'Imp. TSPC', 'Unid. TSPI', 'Imp. TSPI');

    FOR regTemp IN curTemp(regLoc.IdLocalidad) LOOP
    
        --
        -- now we make sure this assignment works ok
        --
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(regTemp.IdCategoria);
        my_row :=xxLxC1_row(regTemp.IdCategoria || '-' || regTemp.Descripcion, regTemp.Cargo_Fijo, 
        regTemp.Importe_C_Fijo, regTemp.kWh, regTemp.Importe_Consumo, regTemp.Cargo_Fijo_GC, 
        regTemp.Imp_C_Fijo_GC, regTemp.Energia_GC, regTemp.Importe_GC, regTemp.Unidades_Demanda, 
        regTemp.Importe_Demanda, regTemp.Cant_BEN, regTemp.BEN, regTemp.Ajuste_Coseno, 
        regTemp.Imp_Ajuste_Coseno, regTemp.Cant_Cargos_Ersep, regTemp.Imp_Cargos_Ersep,
        regTemp.Cant_Ajustes_Ersep, regTemp.Imp_Ajustes_Ersep, regTemp.Unid_Bonif_Exc, 
        regTemp.Imp_Bonif_Exc, regTemp.Unid_Reajustes, regTemp.Imp_Reajustes, regTemp.Unid_Coie, 
        regTemp.Imp_Coie, regTemp.Unid_Coie_Dem, regTemp.Imp_Coie_Dem, regTemp.Unid_TRA1, 
        regTemp.Imp_TRA1, regTemp.Unid_TRA2, regTemp.Imp_TRA2, regTemp.Unid_TSCA, regTemp.Imp_TSCA, 
        regTemp.Unid_TSSA, regTemp.Imp_TSSA, regTemp.UnidBonifCemdo, regTemp.ImpBonifCemdo,
        regTemp.UnidTSPC, regTemp.ImpTSPC, regTemp.UnidTSPI, regTemp.ImpTSPI);
        
     END LOOP;
    
    END LOOP;
END;
/

variable x number
set serverout on
exec :x := xxLocalidadPorCategoria1(...)
```

Comment: as you stated in your answer, that is the solution.